# Update SQL Server connection string on VB.NET EXE without source code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, database-connection

I have a really old application that was created using VB.NET. The original source code has since been deleted and unrecoverable. I have to change the database location and need to update this in the application. I changed the connection string in the .config file, but it seems to be getting it from the exe itself. If I open the exe file in Notepad++ I can see the original connection string. If I edit the file and save it, it no longer works. I get an error saying: "This app cannot run on your PC".

I tried opening the app with Resource Hacker, but don't see the connection string to update. I have Visual Studio 2019 and tried opening the exe file, but also don't see anywhere to edit the connection string.

Comment: I assume that writing the program again from scratch isn't an immediately available option, so you might find [How can I decompile my (dot)NET .EXE file into its source code](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2688/how-can-i-decompile-my-dotnet-exe-file-into-its-source-code) useful.

Comment: If it's network sql server, just make a hosts file entry that points the old, baked-in server name to the new location.. ?

Comment: *If I open the exe file in Notepad++* - ho ho ho.. you need a hex editor. Try HxD.

Comment: @CaiusJard the problem is that the instance name is different as well.

Comment: If it's not one thing, it's your mother! Try a hex editor. Remember that strings aren't ASCII so the ascii side view might look like `D.a.t.a.S.o.u.r.c.e.=.m.y.s.e.r.v.e.r`...

Comment: @CaiusJard Yeah, I searched for the name and edited the values per Hex editor with the dot spacing. I had to edit instead of deleting, since it would detect a file size change and no longer run as an executable. The program runs but get other .NET errors.

Comment: That could be a dependencies thing? If it's old, maybe you don't have a compatible .net framework installed

Comment: @CaiusJard I runs fine with the original connection string (old SQL Server).

Comment: Is there a difference in the versions of sql server? Or some difference in the schema ? What sorts of errors are presenting?

Comment: @CaiusJard Could be that, since I am moving from 2008 to 2019....